# Laravel 5 relationships 3 tables

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

How do i build this relationship

table4 has many table1 id.
table4 has many table2 id.
table4 has many table3 id.

**Table 4**

```
| id | tab1id | tab2id   | tab3id | 
|----|--------|----------|--------|
| 1  | 1      | 2        | 1      |
```

How do i establish the relationship in the model kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

You can establish hasMany relationship with multiple tables by creating another table that contains the relationship mapping between those all.

For example:

1. Create model for the relation (relationTable)
2. Set `belongsTo` relationship for your three tables in `relationTable` (tab1, tab2, tab3).
3. Set `hasMany` relationship to the `relationTable` from `table4`